# Changing an element in a multidimensional array relative to the location of another element

Tags: arrays, ruby

Say I have a multidimensional array...

```
@arr = [[0,0,0,0], [0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]]
```

and I want to change the 0 four indexes from the left of the 1 to a 1, so i.e. the first subarray to become [0,0,1,0]... why doesn't this work...

```
@arr.map! { |x| ( x[1][-2] == 1 ? x[0][-2] = 1 : x ) }
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the result you want?

Comment: By "0 four", do you mean four 0?

Comment: Yeah, I want the 3rd index in the first subarray to change from a 0 to a 1. Pretty much what I'm trying to do is check for wherever there's a 1 I want the fourth and first index to the left and right of the 1 to change from a 0 to a 1. I'm not looking for a solution, I just don't see why my code isn't working.

Comment: There are no multi-dimensional arrays in Ruby, just arrays-of-arrays (and arrays-of-arrays-of-arrays ...).

Answer (score 0):

In your block, `x` now represents each individual sub-array.

```
x = [0, 0, 1, 0]
#=> x[1][-2] = 0
```